# when count is using with string_agg is not counting right in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT concepts.*, 
string_agg(DISTINCT concept_skill, ', ') AS skillsSortedById, 
COUNT (likes.concept_id) AS counted
FROM concepts
INNER JOIN concept_skills ON 
(concepts.concept_id=concept_skills.concept_id)
INNER JOIN likes ON (concepts.concept_id=likes.concept_id)
GROUP BY concept_skills.concept_id, concepts.concept_id
ORDER BY counted desc;
```

somehow when use count with `string_agg` count is multiplying each like by 4 and giving wrong result, but if I use count without `string_agg` it is giving exact result, can anyone help with that why is that?

Comment: Can you please remove the `enter code here`'s from the post and reformat it to be more readable?

Comment: yes shure, sorry about that

Comment: somehow string_agg is affecting to count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are doing the counting after joining.

```
SELECT q.*,  COUNT(l.concept_id) AS counted
FROM (
  SELECT concepts.*, 
  string_agg(DISTINCT concept_skill, ', ') AS skillsSortedById 
  FROM concepts
  INNER JOIN concept_skills ON 
  (concepts.concept_id=concept_skills.concept_id)
  GROUP BY concept_skills.concept_id, concepts.concept_id
) q, likes l
WHERE q.concept_id = l.concept_id
GROUP BY q.concept_id, q.skillsSortedById
ORDER BY counted desc;
```

See my edited [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7053/21/0)

Comment: I have tried that, but it is giving me each counted only by one. anyway thank you so much for your help

Comment: thank you so much sir, I really appreciated, I learnt a lot of things from you. God Bless you!

Comment: I forgot to say that that result was exactly what was needing and you solved that, thank you one more time